# Windows XP compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio-2012, compatibility

I am working on a project that targets Windows XP platform. I have been developing it on a Windows XP virtual Machine with Visual Studio 2008 (with .NET 3.5) to make sure that it is going to work for my client. But this method became annoying (turning on, turning off, minimizing, restoring the virtual machine window, the lower performance). On my native machine, I am using Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate on Windows 7.
If I am going to import the project from that machine to my native one and continue developing it, how can I be sure that it is going to work on Windows XP?

My application is written in C# for .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: Build your application in VS2012 and Win7, make sure you target .Net Framework 3.5. Use the Virtual Win XP to verify that the installation work as before. We had some problems targeting the right .Net version but that was in C++/CLI, it uses 4.0 even when targeting 3.5...

Comment: I will try. But the thing that I do not want to happen is "wow, I wrote so much code, but my application doesn't work in Windows XP, I will have to rewrite everything"

Comment: It should work fine as long as you are targeting 3.5. XP support .Net Framework 3.5. Your more likely to be upset that you can use the cool stuff in .Net Framework 4.5... :)

Comment: @Victor - A .NET Framework 3.5 application cannot do anything not supported by Windows XP because .NET 3.5 is supported by Windows XP. You are worried about a very minor issue, you have access to a Windows  XP virtual machine, and you will still have to confirm changes to your application work on Windows XP no matter what.  VS2008 and VS2012 can also be installed together.

Comment: @MathiasWestin, in my application, I don't actually need the cool features of .NET4.5. I am using them in other projects :D

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you target .Net Framework 3.5 in Visual Studio 2012. 
[How to: Target a Version of the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)

Rebuild the application and test it in the Virtual XP machine. Windows XP is supporting .Net Framework 3.5 so there should be no problems. 
[Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21)

But do tell your client that the Microsoft support for Windows XP is going to end soon so they should start planning an upgrade.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/endofsupport.aspx

Comment: I know about the support end. It is a bit more complicated. But for now, he wants the application on Windows XP

Comment: It will likely be a requirement for years to come to target XP for some customers. Fortunately targeting the 3.5 Framework makes that mostly painless as possible.